# Persisting CKEDITOR 4.2 SCAYT enable/disable status

Tags: ckeditor

If the user enabled SCAYT I would like it to remain enabled across web page loads. That probably means persisting state in a cookie. What is the easiest way to do this?

If there is a way to capture the CKEDITOR SCAYT enable/disable activity that would be fine, alternatively if there is a way to hook into the save event that would also be fine. I tried the following but that just disabled saving entirely, and no log message was generated.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("ckeditor", {
  height: $(window).height() / 2 - 30,
  on: {
    save: function(evt) {
      Console.log("Saving...");
      this.customConfig.scayt_autoStartup = $.cookie("scayt_enabled", "enabled", { path: '/' });
    }
  }
});
```

I put the following in config.js:

```
config.scayt_autoStartup = $.cookie("scayt_enabled",  { path: '/' }) == "enabled";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to the current version of CKEDITOR, which provides a `save` event, it was easy to use a cookie (via JQuery) to accomplish this.

In my editor script:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("ckeditor", {
  save: function(evt) {
    var scaytEnabled = evt.editor.commands.scaytcheck.state==1;
    $.cookie("scayt_enabled", scaytEnabled.toString(), { path: '/' });
  }
}
```

In config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  var scayt_enabled = $.cookie("scayt_enabled");
  var se = scayt_enabled=="true";
  config.scayt_autoStartup = se;
}
```